# Como popular SELECT de um modal criado com JQUERY

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, modal

Tenho um Modal que crio dinamicamente quando o usuário clica em um link, conforme o link ele abre um modal diferente.

Gostaria de popular um Select que esta dentro desse modal. Já tentei so com um include, mas não esta funcionando.

Quando clico, aciono essa função. Que depois executa as outras duas seguintes.

```
$(document).on('click', '.abre-modal-aula', function(){

const typeOperation = $(this).attr("type-operation");
const codAula   = $(this).attr("cod-aula");

$.getJSON('config/database/consultaAjax/includes/modalAulas.php', { codAula, typeOperation }, resultado => {
    if(resultado == '999-login'){
        newAuth();
        return false;
    }
    if(resultado != null){
        const modals = modalActionAula(resultado, typeOperation);
        $('#showModal').html(modals);
        $('#aula').modal();
        setTimeout(() => {
            $('input[type="checkbox"], input[type="radio"]').iCheck({
                checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_square-blue',
                radioClass: 'iradio_square-blue'
            });
            // INICIA O CSS E JS DO SELECT2
            $('select.select2').each(function () {
                $(this).select2({
                    dropdownParent: $(this).parent().parent()
                });
            });
            // INICIA CSS E JS DA MASCARA DE FORMATAÇÃO
            $('[data-mask]').inputmask();
        }, 100);
    }
});
return false;
```

});

```
const modalActionAula = (resultado, typeOperation) => {

switch (typeOperation) {
    case 'verAula':
        return verAula(resultado);
    case 'cancPgto':
        return cancPgto(resultado);
    case 'pagamento':
        return pagamento(resultado, optionFormaPgto);
    case 'pgtoLote':
        return pgtoLote(optionFormaPgto);
    default:
        return false;
}
```

}

```
const verAula = (resultado) => {

return `
<div class="modal fade" id="aula">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Visualização Dados da Aula</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <section class="content">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="box box-primary">
                                <div class="box-body">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="form-group col-md-8">
                                            <label>Professor</label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" value="${resultado.CPROFESSOR}" disabled>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                                            <label>Tipo Aula</label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" value="${resultado.CTIPOAULA}" disabled>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="box box-primary">
                                <div class="box-body">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                                            <label >Selecione o Talento para adicionar na Aula</label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group col-md-8">
                                            <select class="select2 form-control" id="selectTalentoAula" required>
                                                <?php include "pages/includes/lista/listClientes.php" ?>
                                            </select>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group  col-md-4">
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-right addTalentoAula" >Adicionar Talento</button>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                                            <table class="table table-bordered">
                                                <thead>
                                                    <tr>
                                                    <th scope="col">#</th>
                                                    <th scope="col">First</th>
                                                    <th scope="col">Last</th>
                                                    <th scope="col">Handle</th>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </thead>
                                                <tbody>
                                                    <tr>
                                                    <th scope="row">1</th>
                                                    <td>Mark</td>
                                                    <td>Otto</td>
                                                    <td>@mdo</td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                    <th scope="row">2</th>
                                                    <td>Jacob</td>
                                                    <td>Thornton</td>
                                                    <td>@fat</td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                    <th scope="row">3</th>
                                                    <td colspan="2">Larry the Bird</td>
                                                    <td>@twitter</td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </tbody>
                                            </table>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </section>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

`;
```

}

Esse select não esta puxando nada:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-8">
    <select class="select2 form-control" id="selectTalentoAula" required>
        <?php include "pages/includes/lista/listClientes.php" ?>
    </select>
</div>
```

Em outra tela que não é modal ele puxa a lista de clientes normalmente.

Answer (score 0):

Nesta parte do código a baixo, pode alterar:

```
$('select.select2').each(function () {
                $(this).select2({
                    dropdownParent: $(this).parent().parent()
                });
            });
```

Altera para :

```
   $.each(data, function (index, row) {
                $(".selecao-select").append("<option value='" + row.idMateriaPrima + "'>" + row.nomeMateriaPrima + "</option>");
            });
```

Obs: data está recendo os dados